# Looking for "PERC H730P Mini" driver for Solaris 10

Tags: drivers, dell-perc, solaris-10

I can't find the driver for PERC H730P Mini for Solaris 10. The installation in a Dell PowerEdge R730xd fails with "no disks found".

Isn't this controller supported? Where can I get a compatible driver?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the Dell support site for drivers?

Comment: Yes, I only found some Windows drivers

Comment: That probably means there isn't a driver for that OS then.

Answer (score 1):

The [Solaris on Dell PowerEdge servers wiki](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/solaris) lists all of the hardware platforms that Dell supports Solaris 10 with. Note that there is nothing newer that 11th-gen hardware listed, nor any support for Solaris 11 (seems that no validation testing has been done by Solaris for a while now). Your R730xd is a 13th generation system, so you won't find this driver officially provided by Dell.

However, with some quick web searching, you can find that the PERC H730p uses the LSI 3108 ROC... and so does the LSI MegaRAID 9361-8i card. The LSI Support Site shows [plenty of drivers](http://www.lsi.com/support/pages/download-results.aspx?component=Storage+Component&productfamily=RAID+Controllers&productcode=P00834&assettype=Driver&productname=MegaRAID+SAS+9361-8i) for the card, including one for [Solaris 10 & 11](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/RAID%20Controllers/RAID%20Controllers%20Common%20Files/MR_SOLARIS_DRIVER_6.7-6.607.02.00.tgz).

Comment: Thanks! So I tried and loaded this driver during the installation, I also made sure it's loaded using `modinfo | grep sas` (showing mr_sas), but neither Solaris 10 nor 11 seem to list the disks in `cfgadm -al` or `format -e`. Do I have to do more?

Comment: So `modinfo` shows that the kernel module / driver is there... But I'm not certain whether that means the driver is actually in use - maybe that only shows that it's installed? Perhaps check the output of `scanpci -v` to verify that the H730p is actually recognized? Also, have you actually configured any virtual disks from the BIOS of the card? (I'm not aware of a "pass-through" mode for this card for a JBOD mode)

Comment: Yeah, `scapci` identifies the controller. I tried both controller modes - HBA and RAID, and in Ubuntu I can see the disks and mount 'em. In Solaris, however, I only see disks when I export them as RAID0 virtual disks, which I'd like to avoid. How can I check and/or enforce the `mr_sas` driver to be in use?

Comment: It seems like HBA mode would be fully supported by LSI since it's mentioned in Fix/Enhancement "SCGCQ00550384" in the release notes of the Solaris 10/11 driver. Perhaps you'd need to flash the LSI (non-Dell) firmware onto the card to allow this to work as expected?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to load the LSI firmware over the iDrac interface of my Dell server.

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to do it that way. Flashing LSI firmware onto the card is very much unsupported, and should be done with caution as you might brick the card if you do things wrong. I've seen a lot of articles referencing the procedure on the H310 (flashing from IR to IT mode).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your input, you've been very helpful! I admit I gave up on this and now I'm giving ZFS on Ubuntu a try, since I don't seem to be able to use the controller in the HBA mode in Solaris.